# How to debugg Laravel on Windows

Tags: windows, laravel, visual-studio-code

Could you give me a guide to debug a Laravel project using Windows and VSCode?

Comment: What's your setup like? Are you running a WAMP stack, Homestead?

Comment: I installed php 7.1 using Scoop and use valet to display the page on my local computer

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiarized with VSCoded, but I can give you the basis for debugging on Laravel:

Most of the errors you encounter will create an error screen that shows you relevant lines of code. The lines will be in this order: most recent ones on top, oldest ones on the bottom, therefore the error will most likely be near the top.

If you do not recognize the files on the first keep going down until you find something you recognize, many errors go through files that were not created by you. Keep in mind that if your error happens inside your view it will be referenced in a file with a randomly generated name. When this happens the error will mention a file but the line will be dislocated a bit. To know the exact line you can copy the generated name and search it inside your folder.

Most errors will be something really simple like a missing ";" or something like that, you will quickly learn lots of them by copying the error message into google. Laravel is a really popular engine and its really easy to find your errors.

Be careful that some errors do not reference a line, the most common ones are errors on the route. When this happens it is most likely a typo on the file, logic errors, putting get instead of post, etc..., and you'll have to look carefully to find it.

If I remember something else I'll add it here.